# Use Ant to only run specific JUnit tests

Tags: java, ant, junit

We currently have a project set up and have 4 teams working on different parts of it.  I am wanting to have 5 ant targets to run.  One for each team and one additional for production.  But I would like to set an enum in my tests to determine which tests are run.

For example, if a test has.

```
runConfiguration = RunConfigurations.PRODUCTION;
```

Then I would run it to only run for that specific ant target.
And other tests would run if I did:

```
runConfiguration = RunConfigurations.TEAM1;
```

etc.

Is it possible in ant to create a batchtest to only run test with a specific enum value like this?  Or is there perhaps another method to accomplish the same purpose?

Comment: You could probably create different targets, one for prod, one for the others, and one that runs both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you won't be able to do that. The resource collection simply defines the set of java or class files to run as test.

Why don't you simply organize your tests in packages, or even have one source/target directory per set of tests?

```
<batchtest ...>
    <fileset dir="testclasses">
        <include name="com/foo/bar/team1/**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```

or

```
<batchtest ...>
    <fileset dir="testclasses/team1">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```

Comment: One reason why I don't want to do this is because I don't want a package for production.  I don't want to have to keep moving tests over to a production package when they are ready for production.

Comment: Ready or not ready for production should not be handled at this level, IMO. It should be handled by your source management system (SVN, Git, whatever). Develop in a dev branch, and only include what's ready in the prod branch.

Answer (score 1):

What if using [TestSuite](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/junit/framework/TestSuite.html)? Then use ant to execute only desired TestSuites that you want in different occasions.